# Dynamically adding data to a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hey guys! I'm new to Objective C and I need a little help. I've created a UITableView in a UIViewController. I'd like to know how to populate my UITableView dynamically. The data is a bunch of labels that I've stored in a NSMutableArray. So each row displays the contents of the array. Once the array is reloaded with fresh data, the second row will then keep displaying the data as it is added to the array. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

@tableView as you want a particular row i.e second row to display the data after the array(i.e suppose `myArray`) reload for that i suggest u to make one more array of `NSMutableArray` type suppose it is `copymyArray`....and after the reload of myArray give the objects of myArray to copymyArray.
Now at second row index row give copymyArray........and on rest index of tableview give myArray.
Hope this may help u!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please show me a sample code.

Comment: My only means is that make an another array which contains the fresh data i.e data of reloaded array....and give this array to second row i Hope u understand !

Answer (score 0):

Just do this way..................

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *celltype=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:celltype];


    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        //cell.textLabel.text=[[resultarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Service"];

        cell.backgroundView=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]]autorelease];
                            // [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



    }


    UILabel *productCodeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 7, 60,20 )];
    productCodeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    productCodeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    productCodeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Code"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productCodeLabel];
    [productCodeLabel release];

    UILabel *CodeValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 7, 140,20 )];
    CodeValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CodeValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    CodeValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ID"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CodeValueLabel];
    [CodeValueLabel release];



    UILabel *productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 35, 60,20 )];
    productNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    productNameLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    productNameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Name"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productNameLabel];
    [productNameLabel release];

    UILabel *NameValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 35, 140,20 )];
    NameValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NameValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NameValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Title"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:NameValueLabel];
    [NameValueLabel release];



    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 68, 60,20 )];
    dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dateLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dateLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Date"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    [dateLabel release];

    UILabel *dateValueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 68, 140,20 )];
    dateValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dateValueLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    dateValueLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"PostedDate"]];
    dateValueLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    dateValueLabel.numberOfLines=3;
    dateValueLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [dateValueLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateValueLabel];
    [dateValueLabel release];

    /*
     UILabel *DetailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185, 15, 100,20 )];
     DetailLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     DetailLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:DetailLabel];
     [DetailLabel release];*/
    return cell;

}
```

I have array with keys,so i am using key as well.But if you simply have array without keys.Then you don't need to write ValuForKey:@"Id",You can skip value for key.Hope this will help You i gave you the complete code.

Comment: Thanks sabby! I tried something similar. Under the same function, after checking if cell is not equal to nil, I ran a loop beginning from 0 until the number of elements left in my array. Using the loop value, I accessed each label and set it as cell.contentView and then released the label. However nothing showed up. I'm sure there is a flaw in my approach.

Comment: You need to follow the same approach for cell as i did,and then you can also implement your own logic.But don't do else in the if (cell==nil)block ,do what ever after that,looping aur what ever....And try to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I have followed the same approach as you mentioned. I haven not included an else either. after I complete the if loop then I put a for loop. I actually have a change which might make things easier. I want the labels to be displayed in the table only when I push a particular button.

Comment: Really its unable to provide you more solution from my side,without seeing your code.One time you are saying that you are looping,and second time you say that you want to show/hide labels on button click.Where is the button,is that in tableview Cell or outside of that.You can simply use the if else block and set label.hide=TRUE; Or else show your code here so that one can have look,n help you